# Advanced settings for followed people on Twitter

Tags: twitter, list, follow

On Twitter, I'd like to watch specific "followed" people in the Home page (timeline), and watch the others (i.e. celebrities and organizations which have more tweets than my friends) in a list window I created. Is a separation like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking here because this is primarily what twitter lists are used for.

- In the twitter web application, Click "Create a List"
- Find the user you want to "List Follow"
- Click The "List" dropdown.
- Add this user to your newly created list (You do not have to follow the user)

Instructions for [Old Twitter](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/111-features/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists) are here.

Comment: This is what I did; but the problem is I don't want to **copy** these persons, I want to **move** them to the list.

Comment: OK - Place them on the list and *then* unfollow them.